# GeoTIFF LZMA implementation?

Tags: geotiff-tiff

Is GeoTIFF with lzma compression commonly implemented?

I have geotifcp.exe from qgis but doesn't seems implement lzma. 
Is there available sources for libgeotiff with lzma patch?

Comment: I manage to do it myself, it's quite simple to adapt tiffcp.c to geotifcp.c. The lzma2 give output 30% smaller than zip

Comment: However while this is OK for archival purpose, I wonder how widespread lzma GeoTIFF has been?

Comment: Beside geotifcp.exe it seems libtiff.dll (of QGIS or etc) also need to be replaced with libtiff 4.x with lzma enabled